# Mobile Device with custom Bluetooth Devices

Tags: automated-testing, android, mobile, hardware

We are currently looking for a mobile test solution for our latest product.

Since the application is not standalone but works via a Bluetooth connection to 
embedded hardware (smart textile) we are facing difficulties finding an appropriate
testing setup.

Currently the biggest challenge is testing the Bluetooth Stack, as there are subtle differences depending on manufacturer and/or Android Versions and OEMs.

Are there any Mobile Device Clouds which support custom bluetooth devices in their setup?

The other approach we're considering is to build our own setup with the top 10 mobile phones and each time a problem on occurs on a specific device just buy said devices and hope that we get a good coverage in the long run.

Has anybody here faced similar problems? What factors would help us choose between a cloud service and a custom setup?